# How to fetch only value for particular key from json output?

Tags: json, jq

**Objective:**

I want to filter json file by specific key name and to get only its value as output

filter to be used: id (in below json)

**What I tried:**

```
cat /tmp/output.json | jq -r 'values'
{
  "name": "abotcontext7",
  "id": "20436855-4635-49c0-8cc9-a389c569233b",
  "created_at": "2022-06-02T10:39:48.280Z"
}
```

Output should be just: `20436855-4635-49c0-8cc9-a389c569233b`

I tried  `cat /tmp/output.json|jq -r '.id[]`

Its not working. Any suggestions please

Comment: Try `jq -r '.id' /tmp/output.json` or `jq -r 'values.id' /tmp/output.json` (depending on whether you want to filter out `null` or not)

Answer (score 0):

As per @pmf suggestion it worked

```
jq -r 'values.id' /tmp/output.json
```